# Updating a Passbook Pass using Ruby on Rails or an alternative?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passbook

I was wondering how I would go about updating my passes. I already know I need a webServiceURL (which I assume will be your IP address or one set on Ruby on Rails or something) and an authentication token. I'm more focused on how I would actually, physically update it. Is there an easy way out of this? Sort of like those iPhone app creating websites (but you don't professionally code it). I'm going to look into it more, but there aren't too many resources on the internet to choose from (that are useful).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a WYSIWYG, point and click solution, you might want to check out our service [PassKit](https://create.passkit.com).

To see how updates work, you can start with [this demo pass](https://pass.is/krERrj), flip it over and push yourself an update.  You can [import the template](https://create.passkit.com/loader/?t=LN5Ew6kkzxf4sW1ze3i0&c=1) for the demo direct into the pass creator, edit it, and be pushing updates to your own passes within 5 minutes.

We also have a fully functional API that allows your to update and push a new pass your pass in a single call, E.g.

```
https://api.passkit.com/v1/pass/update/template/yourTemplateName/serial/yourPassSerial/push/?field_value1=newValue&field_value2=newValue2
```

If you want some code to get you stated, you can also access the source code to our pass creation pages.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to roll your own,  I would use passbook-ios or something like that which is a Ruby Gem.  If you want to use a service Urban Airship has one....though the pricing is a bit expensive at 10 cents a pass.

Lance